# How to differentiate function related to bloom filters?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, function-and-relation-composition, data-structure

I am trying to understand a scribe note on choosing the right number of hash functions $k$ for a bloomfilter of size $n$ and $m$ elements. The following is stated:

Suppose we are given the ratio $\frac{m}{n}$ and want to optimize the number $k$. If $$g=\ln(f)=k\ln(1-e^{-kn/m})$$ and we let $p=e^{-kn/m}$. Then the derivative of $g$ is: $$\frac{dg}{dk}=\ln(1-p)+\frac{kn}{m}\cdot\frac{p}{1-p}$$
This confuses me because when I try to differentiate $g$ I get the following: $$\begin{equation} \frac{dg}{dk}=\ln(1-p)+\frac{1}{1-e^{-km/n}} \cdot \frac{e^{-km/n} \cdot m-kn}{m^2} \end{equation}$$

Link to equation (on page 2): [http://people.math.gatech.edu/~randall/AlgsF09/bloomfilters.pdf](http://people.math.gatech.edu/%7Erandall/AlgsF09/bloomfilters.pdf)

Comment: You can't derive w.r.t. to an integer, so it is probably assumed that $k\in\mathbb R$ for the derivative. How did you try to differentiate $g$ yourself? If you differentiate $e^{\alpha k}$ with respect to $k$, there is no way that a factor $k$ appears. $\frac{d}{dk} e^{-\alpha k} = -\alpha e^{-\alpha k}$

Comment: I realise that I have made a mistake. I will correct it

Comment: @GoldenRetriever You used the chain rule. So you have to find the derivative of the denominator of $(1-p(k))$ which is $-p^{'}(k)=\frac{n}m\cdot p(k)$ Here you have to use the chain rule again.

Comment: Your term $\frac{1}{1-e^{-kn/m}}(1-e^{-km/n}) $ does not make sense.

Comment: @YvesDaoust right. Corrected now.

Comment: Now $\frac{1}{1-e^{-km/n}} \cdot \frac{e^{-km/n} \cdot m-kn}{m^2} $ does not make sense.

Comment: the point is that I have not done it right. I have not applied the chain rule as Calvin puts it in his answer.

Comment: Bloom filters deserve a capital "B" because it is a certain Mr Bloom that has defined them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you also have to differentiate $p$ as it depends on $k$. It goes like this: first note
$$ \frac{d}{dk} p = \frac d{dk} e^{-kn/m} =-\frac{n}{m} e^{-kn/m} =-\frac{n}{m}p$$
Then applying product rule and chain rule,
\begin{align} \frac{dg}{dk} = \frac{d}{dk}(k(\ln(1-p))
&=\ln(1-p) + k\frac{d}{dk}(\ln (1-p))\\
&=\ln(1-p) + k\frac{\frac{d}{dk}(1-p)}{1-p}\\
&=\ln(1-p) + k\frac{0-\frac{dp}{dk}}{1-p}\\
&=\ln(1-p) + k \frac{-\left(-\frac nmp\right)}{1-p}\\
&=\ln(1-p)+\frac{kn}m\cdot\frac{p}{1-p}
\end{align}

Comment: 1. I am not sure what you are doing in the first note? 2. How do I know that I need to differentiate for $k$ as well? I just thought that I should try to find the derivative for everything on the right side of the equation, and then I am good.

Comment: aah okay. So when I use the chain rule I have to differentiate what I pulled down from the exponent as well?

Comment: @GoldenRetriever yes. I added details for point 1, hopefully it is clear

Comment: totally :) the first note is what you are applying at the last chain right?

Comment: @GoldenRetriever yes exactly

Comment: Now, since we have $\frac{dg}{dk}$ could I say that the function $g$ is actually $g(k)$? I.e. the derivative of $g$ with respect to $k$?

Comment: How is that you go from $\frac{d}{dk}e^{-kn/m}$ to $-\frac{n}{m}e^{-kn/m}$. I am confused about where the $k$ goes ?

Comment: @GoldenRetriever the derivative of $e^{\lambda k}$ is $\lambda e^{\lambda k}$?

Comment: @GoldenRetriever for the first question, yes, sort of, but you could say that $g$ is "actually" $g(k,n,m)$, or maybe you prefer to say $g$ is "actually" $g(p(k))$. Pure mathematics books at undergraduate level and up try to avoid this kind of notation (sorry, I was away and didn't notice the first question)

Comment: alrighty. thanks again.

Comment: I am sorry, but I still don't see how $\frac{d}{k}(-kn/m)=-\frac{n}{m}$. I have tried to do this: $\frac{d}{dk}(-k\cdot \frac{n}{m})=-k\cdot \frac{d}{dm}(\frac{n}{m})-(\frac{n}{m}) = \frac{-kn}{m^
2}+\frac{-n}{m}$

Comment: @GoldenRetriever, $\frac{d}{dk}( Ck) = C$. Here, $C = -\frac{n}{m}$

Comment: So we would do anything more to $C=-n/m$ because there is no $k$ in it?

Comment: @GoldenRetriever this is highly dependent on context. In your case $n,m$ do **not** depend on $k$, so you are done. But e.g. if  $n$ was a function of $k$, then you need to continue  $$ \frac d{dk}{\frac{-n}m k} = \frac{-n}m + k\frac{- \frac{dn}{dk}}m$$

Comment: okay, because I was confused that $C$ didn't become $0$ since $\frac{d}{dk}(\frac{n}{m})=0$

Comment: @GoldenRetriever The $C$ only becomes 0 if you differentiate it. You *can* apply product rule to $Ck$ and then you will have to use this fact:
$$ \frac d{dk} (Ck) = \frac{dC}{dk} k + C \frac{dk}{dk} = 0\times k + C \times 1 = C$$
this result is the same as what I said earlier

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120453/discussion-between-calvin-khor-and-goldenretriever).

Answer (score 1):

$$g=k\ln(1-e^{-kn/m})$$ and

$$\frac{dg}{dk}=\ln(1-e^{-kn/m})+k\frac{\dfrac nme^{-kn/m}}{1-e^{-kn/m}}=\ln(1-p)+\frac{kn}m\frac{p}{1-p}.$$

I don't see any problem.

---

You can also work this out as follows:

$$\frac{dp}{dk}=-\frac nm p$$

and

$$\frac{d(k\log(1-p)}{dk}=\log(1-p)-k\frac{\dfrac{dp}{dk}}{1-p}
\\=\log(1-p)+\frac{kn}m\frac{p}{1-p}.$$

Comment: nice. How is that you go from $\frac{d}{dk}e^{-kn/m}$ to $-\frac{n}{m}e^{-kn/m}$. I am confused about where the $k$ goes?

Comment: @GoldenRetriever: come on, that's the derivative of an exponential.

Comment: right. thanks. much appreciated.